# Mpdf\MpdfException Invalid size representation "a3"

Tags: php, mpdf, laravel-5.6

using mpdf library to generate pdf by loading view files but it throws

> Mpdf\MpdfException Invalid size representation "a3"

**Code**

```
 $pdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8']);
 $pdf->WriteHTML(view()->make('reports.transactions.report', [
                'transactions' => $transactions,
                'from'         => $start ? $start->format('d-M-Y') : '',
                'to'           => $end ? $end->format('d-M-Y') : '',
                'generatedOn'  => Carbon::now()->format('d-M-Y h:i:s'),
                'credit'       => $this->getTotalCredits($transactions),
                'debit'        => $this->getTotalDebits($transactions),
            ]));

 return $pdf->Output('transaction_pdf.pdf','D');
```

using `Laravel 5.6`, `PHP 7.1`. and `bootstrap 4` for styling

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also having this error. It does have something to do with Bootstrap4. But still looking into it.

BS4 sets:

```
@page {
size: a3; }
```

It seems mPdf does not recognize this or BS4 uses a wrong style-attribute. If you use the sass-version of BS4, then you can change it with the var:

```
// Printing
$print-page-size:    a3 !default;
```

Update:
I looked at: https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html
And set the page-size to 'auto' in BS4. The error disappeared although my page is not working yet ;-) But that is something else.

Greetz, flexjoly